# In The Martian, how were the crew in the Hermes shielded from radiation?

Tags: spaceship, space-exploration, the-martian, andy-weir

I have not read the book of The Martian, but there was one glaring omission in the movie that struck me.

How were the crew in the Hermes protected from radiation?

In space, especially interplanetary space, radiation is a big problem.
Look at this from [Wired](http://www.wired.com/2014/04/radiation-risk-iss-mars/):

> A new study highlights one of the big problems with extended space travel: galactic cosmic ray radiation. According to the report, astronauts on the International Space Station would receive doses that exceed their lifetime limits after just 18 months for women and two years for men. A Mars mission crew would be spending at least this long in the harsh radiation of deep space.

The Hermes looks very pretty, but it is all windows and gyms. Not much that would protect from a radiation storm. Even when the crew are discussing doing another round trip, the fact that they are massively increasing their own cancer risk is not mentioned.

Is this covered in the book at all?

Comment: Valeri Polyakov spent 14 months in space in one go, and 22 months total. Gennady Padalka spent 27 months total. So I guess the 18 months limit is a safe bet.

Comment: @Agent_L: apollo's answer adds some detail, the NASA lifetime limit "would raise the lifetime risk of cancer by 3 percent". So not precisely "safe", but it's by no means surprising if those two people exceeded it and are fine so far.

Comment: @SteveJessop My point exactly - it's an acceptable trade-off for someone willing to risk life by travel to Mars.

Comment: He also addresses the question in this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wq3xtZ8AjPE

Comment: @Agent_L, both Valeri Polyakov and Gennady Padalka were on a space station. That is completely different from a trip to Mars or even to the moon because the space stations are always inside the outer boundaries of the Van Allen belt (generally on a low earth orbit). Any travel outside of the Van Allen belt requires better radiation shielding than what is used on the space station.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It was [handwaved](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/martian-astronaut-would-get-cancer-if-mission-were-real-author-says1/).

> “In the book they have this really thin, light, flexible material that blocks all radiation,” says Andy Weir, author of the book The Martian on which the film was based. “There’s nothing even remotely like that in the real world. That was the magic I gave him so the story would progress. Otherwise Mark would have different kinds of cancer.”

Comment: "Hand Waved" not something I was familiar with http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HandWave (warning TV tropes link)

Comment: I liked the film and that a lot of effort had been put into some of the science, which was why I was curious about the radiation. Which is not even hand waved in the film.

Comment: @JeremyFrench There was actually a lot of handwaving in the book/film. For example even the big Martian storm is unrealistic as Martian winds are very mild (estimated to top out ~6mph). That being said Andy Weir acknowledged a lot of it and its all for the purpose of moving the story forward.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Martian winds are a lot faster than 6mph (http://mars.nasa.gov/news/whatsnew/index.cfm?FuseAction=ShowNews&NewsID=1854 says 60mph). They may top out at the *force* of an Earthly 6mph wind though because of the thin air.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thats probably what I meant :)

Comment: One thing I did notice in the film is that they quoted the wind force in Newtons rather than in kph or mph. Of course, either the quoted force was insufficient to knock anything over, or was too strong to have been produced in Mars' atmosphere, so it essential duct tapes over the problem, but hey, at least they acknowledged the issue.

Comment: Material that blocks all radiation... an interesting choise for a _window_... just saying.

Comment: You would need to build something like the Project Orion ship out of Footfall. Big and heavy, with two metre thick walls filled with ice that can be converted to steam and used for vectoring thrust or even heavy braking.

Comment: Selective radiation blocking windows are definitely a thing; you can have UV or IR resistant windows in your house, or block ionising radiation: https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn26256-manhattan-project-radiation-proof-window-for-sale/

Comment: There is actually a company that recently (e.g. late last year) unveiled a highly radiation-proof transparent metal. Trekkies may know it as Transparent Aluminum. http://www.surmet.com/technology/alon-optical-ceramics/ So, just because the Hermes *looks* like it's plastered with windows, in reality it might be plastered with this metal. The Mars Habs could be, too. Or at least they could use [translucent concrete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LiTraCon).

Comment: @TylerH In reality there is no such thing as "radiation-proof".  Different materials offer varying amounts of protection from different *types* of radiation roughly proportional to their thickness. So some radiation always gets through, and some *types* of radiation are more affected by some materials, but not by others.  Visible Light, for instance is a type of radiation that is clearly largely unimpeded by anything "transparent", aluminum or otherwise.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Notice I said *highly* radiation-proof.

Comment: @TylerH But it is not.  The link you provide makes no such claim and it is obviously not "proof" against visible radiation at all.  And it is very likely no more proof against cosmic radiation than anything else we have (which is not very much at all).

Answer (score 49):

### He would die with that kind of protection.

There were some inaccuracies in the book and the plot. But it was a great book anyway.

*That list of doom:*

**1. Atmosphere**

On a reddit Q&A, one fan asked Weir if such withering storms were possible on Mars.

> **Weir's answer:** "No. Mars’s atmosphere is too thin. This was a deliberate concession to
>   drama that I made because it’s a man-versus-nature story and I wanted
>   nature to get the first punch in."

**2. Cosmic Rays (Radiaiton Poisoning)** `(ANSWERING YOU HERE)`

After being left alone on Mars, Watney makes his way toward the Schiaparelli crater. Spending that much time on the planet would expose him to a dangerous, and probably fatal, amount of cosmic rays, if not for his handy (and fictional) radiation blocker.

> "The book has a completely fictional material that blocks radiation. No such thin, flexible, light radiation shielding exists in the real world" —
>   Andy Weir, author, 'The Martian'

NASA limits its astronauts to between .8 and 1.2 sieverts of lifetime radiation exposure, which would raise the lifetime risk of cancer by 3 percent. Because the sample size of astronauts who have spent a considerable time in space is so small, the exact health effects of cosmic ray exposure is clouded with uncertainty.

The most effective shields against cosmic rays, like water or liquid hydrogen, tend to be heavy and not portable—meaning they’re suitable inside the walls of a space capsule, but impractical in a spacesuit. Researchers are working on plastic cosmic ray shields, but haven’t gotten there yet.

**3. Producing Water**

Watney mixes hydrazine, a toxic substance usually handled by people in hazmat suits, and oxygen to make drinking water. The admixture also produces ammonia which is poisonous.

> “Yes, very toxic. I didn’t know that at the time. Had I known, I would
>   have had him wear his EVA suit during the process,” Weir replied during the Q&A.

- [Source](http://www.theepochtimes.com/n3/1767813-the-martian-author-andy-weir-separates-fact-from-fiction-in-reddit-ama/)

Comment: At least this author did all the research and made conscious decisions about when to break the realm of scientific reason for the sake of plot instead of simply being oblivious to it, or in the few cases he actually messed up, admitted to it.

Comment: @corsiKa I agree, in fact The Martian is one of my all time favourites. He is also a developer, which makes him even cooler.

Comment: Do you mean he would die *without* that kind of protection?

Comment: @Paul No, I actually meant what it says. Read the second explanation. The provided protection is not enough to survive the cosmic rays. He would die because of radiation poisoning.

Comment: Oh, "that kind of protection" means "normal thin shielding". I was reading it as "radiation shielding" in general.

Comment: I was confused by that header as well, and eventually decided you meant he would die with windows and gyms as protection, which is also confusing since you seem to be talking about Mark on the planet, not on the ship.

Comment: I was talking about Mark only but the same is true for the rest of Ares crew as well. I explained in the second part.

Comment: @apollo - Damaged yes, die no. Take a look at this: http://www.anser.org/docs/The_Radiation_Threat_to_the_Martian.pdf. OK, the help lies about that kind of link. Trying again.

Comment: @Kaine Even 3% of fatal cancer is highly dangerous. He would eventually get cancer and die. I didn't mean he would die right away on Mars. He would die after some time, when the cancer is developed enough. Today, women go in to surgeries to remove their breasts because they carry breast cancer gene. Cancer is dangerous. Don't underestimate 3%.

Comment: @apollo I understand the number as "the chance of developing cancer is 3% higher than under normal (earth) circumstances". Not as "a little bit of fatal cancer".

Comment: @Twinkles I believe people take it as a low chance but it is a really high possibility when considering this is cancer.

Comment: @apollo It's an additional 3% chance. That's usually considered a relatively low chance; as of 2014 (according to the American Cancer Society) the risk of an American man dying from cancer is 22.83%. Going from 22.8% to 25.8% isn't a huge jump. It might also worth considering that over the last few decades, astronauts have run about a 3% chance of dying on the job. They do tend to be (sane and rational) risk-takers.

Comment: @Kaine According to [cencerresearchuk.org](http://www.cancerresearchuk.org/health-professional/cancer-statistics/risk/lifetime-risk), 1 in 2 people born after 1960 in the UK will be diagnosed with some form of cancer during their lifetime. This is 50% risk for an average being in UK. But in [seer.cancer.org](http://seer.cancer.gov/csr/1975_2012/results_merged/topic_lifetime_risk.pdf), it is shown that the chance of diagnosed with canver is aroun 40%. This is only for average circumstances. When you consider you're exposed to cosmic rays w/o any form of protection... 1/2

Comment: @Kaine Your chances of developing cancer peaks. You have to consider this is not some _natural_ way to develop cancer (not that cancer is something natural). You are being exposed to lethal radiation. And I'm not even adding how Watney used a radioactive core to warm himself during his journey from the hub to the crater. He would eventually get (after more than 500 sols on Mars + journey to Earth in Hermes) lethal cancer. The chances of survival depends on the treatment he gets when he arrives Earth. But I wouldn't say it would be very effective for his condition. 2/2